# Does AWS DocumentDB support MongoDB 2dshpere index?

Tags: aws-documentdb-mongoapi

i'm trying run existing application with a new AWS DocumentDB service. From mongo shell i tried to run 
`db.geojson.createIndex( { geoData : "2dsphere" , sessionId:1 } )`
and received
`{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Index type not supported : 2dsphere", "code" : 303 }`

this code works well with actual MongoDb instance, but not with new AWS service, which supposed to be compatible with MongoDB 3.6

Comment: Right after posting was able to find an answer, AWS DocumentDB has quite poor index support, no 2dsphere or text index https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis-index.html

Comment: Can you fix the typo in "2dsphere" for the sake of indexing and search please?

Answer (score 5):

No. AWS DocumentDB does not support geospatial index or queries. There are several index limitations detailed here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis-index.html

In order to use 2dsphere index you can use MongoDB Atlas on AWS and have access to the full set of MongoDB API and features.

https://cloud.mongodb.com

Answer (score 1):

These are the [indexes supported by DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) at the time of this posting:

```
Single Field Index - Yes
Compound Index     - Yes
Multikey Index     - Yes
Text Index         - No
2dsphere           - No
2d Index           - No
Hashed Index       - No
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for 2dsphere indexes was added to Amazon DocumentDB in October 2021.

Comment: Except that `2dsphere` is not available for *polygons*, if such is his use case.

Comment: Correct, while 2dsphere indexes are supported the only GeoJSON Type that can currently be indexed is "Point".